# SQL - Get count of phone calls that resulted in meeting

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named 'reports', something like this:

| id | user_id | type | customer_id | text | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | .... | 2021-08-07 17:00:52 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 | .... | 2021-08-12 10:11:11 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 9 | .... | 2021-08-12 10:08:14 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 3 | .... | 2021-08-12 10:04:08 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 9 | .... | 2021-08-13 20:32:21 |
| 6 | 2 | 1 | 7 | .... | 2021-08-13 20:34:17 |
| 7 | 2 | 2 | 8 | .... | 2021-08-14 18:55:09 |

I want to get the count of rows that a user has submitted type 1 reports that result in a type 2 report.

Type 1 report means reporting a phone call to the customer and type 2 means meeting the customer. I want to receive the number of calls that resulted in an meeting.

For example, for user 1 should returns 3, because for customer 3, IDs 1 and 2 have led to ID 4, and for customer 9, ID 3 has led to ID 5.

But for user 2, ID 7 is type 2 but there is no previous type 1 report for customer 8, so it returns 0.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Could you please share your code with us as well?

Comment: ➕1 you can show a real example of your data with queries here for instance http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: I don't see the relationships. How do IDs 1 and 2 lead to ID 4, and ID 3  leads to ID 5? But in general, the answer to questions like this is a self-join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE reports
    (id int auto_increment primary key,
     user_id int, 
     type int, 
     customer_id int, 
     text varchar(4), 
     created_at varchar(19)
    );
    
INSERT INTO reports
    (id, user_id, type, customer_id, text, created_at)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 3, '....', '2021-08-07 17:00:52'),
    (2, 1, 1, 3, '....', '2021-08-12 10:11:11'),
    (3, 1, 1, 9, '....', '2021-08-12 10:08:14'),
    (4, 1, 2, 3, '....', '2021-08-12 10:04:08'),
    (5, 1, 2, 9, '....', '2021-08-13 20:32:21'),
    (6, 2, 1, 7, '....', '2021-08-13 20:34:17'),
    (7, 2, 2, 8, '....', '2021-08-14 18:55:09');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT x.user_id
     , COUNT(DISTINCT y.id) total
  FROM reports x
LEFT
JOIN reports y 
  ON y.id<=x.id
 AND y.user_id = x.user_id
 AND y.customer_id = x.customer_id
 AND y.type = 1
WHERE x.type = 2
GROUP
   BY x.user_id;
```

| user_id | total |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 0 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6toXUvJvLvVF2QJLkeZB1c/1)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown how your are expecting results, but simply refer to User 1 and 2 and the total votes, you can try using a `lateral join`

```
select user_id, Coalesce(Sum(valid),0) rowcount
from reports r
join lateral (
    select 
    case when exists (select * from reports rr 
            where rr.user_id=r.user_Id and rr.type=2 and rr.customer_id=r.customer_Id and r.type=1)
    then 1 end valid
)x
group by User_Id
```

[Example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=04271243f7e55cfb8b322bc178f08cf6)

Answer (score 0):

First you  Count the number of customers that comply with your criterioa type and typoe 2. But ti get all user you need to join the list of users

I used LEFT join as also RIGHt JOIN in my example

> ```
> CREATE TABLE reports
>     (`id` int, `user_id` int, `type` int, `customer_id` int, `text` varchar(4), `created_at` varchar(19))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO reports
>     (`id`, `user_id`, `type`, `customer_id`, `text`, `created_at`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 1, 1, 3, '....', '2021-08-07 17:00:52'),
>     (2, 1, 1, 3, '....', '2021-08-12 10:11:11'),
>     (3, 1, 1, 9, '....', '2021-08-12 10:08:14'),
>     (4, 1, 2, 3, '....', '2021-08-12 10:04:08'),
>     (5, 1, 2, 9, '....', '2021-08-13 20:32:21'),
>     (6, 2, 1, 7, '....', '2021-08-13 20:34:17'),
>     (7, 2, 2, 8, '....', '2021-08-14 18:55:09')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT IFNULL(Counts,0),t1.user_id
> FROM (SELECT COUNT(distinct r.customer_id) counts,user_id
> FROM reports r 
> WHERE type = 1 AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM reports WHERE type = 2 AND customer_id = r.customer_id)
> GROUP BY user_id) r RIGHT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROm reports) t1 ON r.user_id = t1.user_id
> ```
>
> ```
> IFNULL(Counts,0) | user_id
> ---------------: | ------:
>                2 |       1
>                0 |       2
> ```

> ```
> SELECT IFNULL(Counts,0),t1.user_id
> FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROm reports) t1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(distinct r.customer_id) counts,user_id
> FROM reports r 
> WHERE type = 1 AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM reports WHERE type = 2 AND customer_id = r.customer_id)
> GROUP BY user_id) r  ON r.user_id = t1.user_id
> ```
>
> ```
> IFNULL(Counts,0) | user_id
> ---------------: | ------:
>                2 |       1
>                0 |       2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a837a51682961f1aba0cb579818d28dc)*